# Does fstrim wear out SSD

Tags: ssd

I bought a samsung 840 pro 250 GB ssd ~two months ago, and I was wondering how much has been written to it. Actually, I have four partitions: /,/home,boot, and swap. To figure out how much was written to home, I wrote

`$cat /sys/fs/ext4/sda7/lifetime_write_kbytes`

the output was `8,985,606,440` (I added the commas). So that's 8TB. I was wondering to myself, boy I must be writing a lot. I wonder how? I monitored how much I wrote from browsing the internet and other common tasks, then I remembered that I set up a daily cron to do fstrim, because the internet told me to. So I ran

`$sudo fstrim -v /home`

and the output was `606,591,360` bytes were trimmed.

Then I ran

`$cat /sys/fs/ext4/sda7/lifetime_write_kbytes`

again and sure enough I get `8,986,209,516`. So my writes increased 600MB. Now this is not really enough to account for 8TB of writes, but I had just run fstrim a few minutes earlier, so I think fstrim usually trims a lot more than 600 MB. I will have to confirm this.

Regardless, do the writes caused by fstrim actually count towards decreasing the life of your SSD? I had the impression they didn't.

## Edit

I don't have to guess how much is typically trimmed by the cron job. It turns out the internet told me to log the output of fstrim. Looking at the log, I see it trimmed an average of about 150 GB/day since Aug 24, 150 GB/day * 60 days is about 9 TB. So I think the fstrim does account for the 9TB of writes I have to my SSD.

## Edit 2

smart was not enabled on the SSD, but I ran `$sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda7`. Then I ran `$sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda7`. This was the output:

```
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-3.8.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series
Serial Number:    S1ATNSAD780426K
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 5a00ae961
Firmware Version: DXM05B0Q
User Capacity:    256,060,514,304 bytes [256 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 4c
Local Time is:    Wed Oct 30 09:43:18 2013 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (53956) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  20) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       458
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   072   068   000    Old_age   Always       -       28
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       4294967148
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       748699270

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]


SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
  255        0    65535  Read_scanning was never started
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: How often do you hit swap? If the answer is "more than almost never", that could easily account for your counts.

Comment: I set swappiness to 1 because the internet told me so. And I don't hibernate. Whenever I open system monitor, it says I am using 0 bytes of swap.

Comment: My guess is that the TRIM commands sent by fstrim are being counted as writes by the ext4 driver, even though they aren't actually writes. What does SMART say? Run `smartctl -a /dev/sdsa7` (you may have to install smartmontools first) and look at the Host_Writes* and NAND_Writes* fields.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner I didn't see the fields you mentioned, but please see edit 2.

Comment: I guess Samsung drives don't share that information. I do have those fields on my Intel.

Comment: Samsung doesn't report actual nand writes in SMART. You can only **incraese** the lifespan of your drive by trimming, because it allows the controller to arrange writes more evenly. (Well, on the other hand, Samsung Magician in Windows does somehow show a value named "Total Bytes Written", but I am not sure where it gets it from.)

Comment: So it's looking like the answer is that fstrim does not wear out your ssd; on the contrary, it increases its lifespan. The writes reported in lifetime_write_kbytes refer to file system writes at a higher abstraction level and don't necessarily correspond to physical writes to the drive.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton ok, 8TB is kinda much, but it isn't really? I mean, for a 250GB drive it is just 32 write cycles, if distributed evenly (let's hope the SSD controller does that) Surely, we can endure _much_ more than that? And I think we could support hibernating, too - writing, say, 8GB of RAM to disk every now and then (you don't hibernate every 5 minutes, do you?) won't add up to too much, or will it?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov, I'm not sure why you are bringing up hibernation. I was talking about swap. The 840 Pro warranties 40 GB/day for 5 year operation (http://www.samsung.com/us/pdf/memory-storage/840PRO_25_SATA_III_Spec.pdf); the OP's use is well outside of that. The drive itself seems to have a 1000 - 3000 Write/Erase cycle; it is inappropriate to place swap storage on this drive.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Sorry, it was NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs who talked about hibernation. Wow, the warranted write of 40GB/day is not _that_ much. Where can I see the 1000 - 3000 cycles figure? I would like to double-check the figures for the drives I'm considering (840 EVO and PRO) now that you brought to my attention that my intended usage might, in fact, strain the drive's endurance.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton My Intel 520 is rated at [5000 cycles](http://ssdendurancetest.com/ssd-endurance-test-report/Intel-SSD-520-60) (failed to see that [in the spec](http://download.intel.com/newsroom/kits/ssd/pdfs/intel_ssd_520_product_spec_325968.pdf), too), and I know the general trend is downward, but I didn't check and I hoped the Samsung '840 series are not much worse than Intel 520 in this regard.

Comment: [Here](http://www.vojcik.net/samsung-ssd-840-endurance-destruct-test/) a guy writes 3 PB to a 128GB Samsung 840 PRO before it dies. Sounds reassuring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

fstrim does not wear out your ssd; on the contrary, it increases its lifespan. The writes reported in lifetime_write_kbytes refer to file system writes at a higher abstraction level and don't necessarily correspond to physical writes to the drive. So although there are 40 TB of writes reported in lifetime_write_kbytes, running `$sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda7` followed by  `$sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda7` reveals that I have only written 750,000,000 blocks of 512 bytes each, which comes out to 375GB, which is a more reasonable value for two months of use.

Answer (score 1):

trims are counted as writes in `lifetime_write_kbytes` as well as in all other Linux level statistics I know of, like `iostat` or `sar`, see [posting](https://superuser.com/questions/1477784). The write statistics is easily dominated by trims counted as writes, especially for moderately filled file systems.

In other words: `lifetime_write_kbytes` is not a reliable estimate for the amount of data written to a SSD disk.