# fstrim trimming a lot of bytes, don't think I did that much deletion

Tags: ssd, trim

Recently I install a SSD on my Linux Mint 17.1 system. I configured the common things like io scheduler to be noop, mount /tmp and /var/log over tmpf, running fstrim for both root and home partitions on startup using rc.local. I have 8gb of ram so I also removed swap partition.

But right after logging to the system and doing 5-10 minutes of console only stuff, when I executed the fstrim command, it trimmed close to 300mb. I did not download anything during this time.

So my question is why so much of amount of bytes that is trimmed. I didn't delete any big files. What could be it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is some information about that here http://superuser.com/questions/667412/does-fstrim-wear-out-ssd?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:**  fstrim is reporting an incorrect number of trimmed bytes.

A very [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371662/why-fstrim-appears-not-to-trim-data-blocks-on-btrfs-ecrypts/371665#371665) was asked on Unix Stackexchange. The accepted answer states:

> It is a common misunderstanding to worry about the sizes reported by
>   fstrim.
>
> It really doesn't mean anything. Just ignore it.
>
> fstrim just issues the appropriate ioctl, everything else is the
>   decision of the filesystem, and filesystems behave very differently.
>   For example, ext4 tries to avoid trimming the same things over and
>   over, so you will see 0 bytes trimmed. xfs doesn't care and trims
>   everything that's free, so you'll always see 
>   bytes trimmed. Other filesystems may do other things, it all depends
>   on how the filesystem chose to implement the FITRIM syscall logic, if
>   it's implemented at all.
>
> As long as the amount of data trimmed is not larger than free space,
>   you should be fine regardless of what fstrim (the filesystem, really)
>   reports.
>
> In the end only the SSD itself really knows what's currently trimmed
>   and what not. Trimming already trimmed blocks does not cause any harm
>   whatsoever.
>
> Don't make conclusions based on x bytes trimmed as reported by fstrim.
>
> If you want to verify that data was trimmed, you have to check raw
>   data on the disk. ( https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85880/30851 ) but
>   that method might not work for btrfs, I have never tried.

I asked the OP about the exact case that you describe (an ext4 filesystem reporting a few hundred MB trimmed even though no significant write activity or deletions have occurred. He responded with:

> Once you make a small change, it will trim a large area (but still
>   smaller than free space). Also it might not remember across reboots. I
>   haven't looked at the implementation in detail, I guess it's just not
>   that fine grained.